# How to get records that must match multiple values from same column field in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am running Crystal Reports version XI. I have a table "PatientRecords", which has the following columns name, dob, health programs, address etc. I want to return all the patient's names where health programs they only have APS or they have APS and TCS. A patient may appear multiple times in the table with different health programs. All the possible health programs are APS, TCS, SELF and/or SPARK.

In crystal reports record formula, i tried to type:

```
{PatientRecords.coverage} = "APS" or
({PatientRecords.coverage} = "APS" and {PatientRecords.coverage}="TCS")
```

This gives me only people with APS only programs but it doesn't return any patients that have both APS and TCS. How do I get Crystal Reports to return the correct data?

```
Sample data: 
    John Smith, 03-21-1976, APS, 123 Test Way, Visit 1
    Jane Murai, 02-15-1965, TCS, 2312 Apple Way, Visit 1
    Richard Sams, 05-30-1985, APS, 33 Bans Way, Visit 1
    John Smith, 03-21-1976, TCS, 123 Test Way, Visit 2
    Jane Murai, 02-15-1965, APS, 2312 Apple Way, Visit 2
```

So each patient visit is a record and each record can have different coverages, either APS, TCS, SELF or SPARK. So a person can appear MULTIPLE times, but with different coverages.

Comment: I guess this question was asked before.. why it is asked again and what happen to the previous question

Answer (score 0):

the issue there is that APS and TCS are contained under the same field, so the only thing you have to do is change your search criteria to {PatientRecords.coverage} = "APS" or {PatientRecords.coverage}="TCS" so it will return both records

Answer (score 0):

{PatientRecords.coverage} in ["APS","TCS"]